# send latitude and longitude in the URI to call WCFRest service

Tags: wcf, latitude-longitude

I have a wcfrest method that takes 2 argument, latitude and longitude.
The interface is:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
           UriTemplate =  "/json/location/{lat}/{lon}")]
List<EntityModel.Location> getLocation(string lat,string lon);
```

But when I test the service in the browser, it gives me error. it says "Resource not found".  the url: http://localhost:52747/Location.svc/json/location/52.0222/12.3698

I believe this is because lat/lon in double value (12.255888, 55.23657).
Any ideas how to solve it??

Comment: What is the base url for your service, have you tried to call http://localhost:52747/json/location/52.0222/12.3698 ?

Comment: yes. i tried that. dosn't work. same error. But if I remove the remove the double value and use 12/55 instead, it works.

Comment: Is the service configured to show you its WSDL? Is it showing?

Comment: It is not properly configured. But if I browse http://localhost:52747/Location.svc?wsdl, it shows the operation name.

Comment: Have you tried changing your method signature to getLocation(double lat,double lon); ?

Comment: yes. I did. But it says variable in the URI template must be of type string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.
may be http://localhost:52747/Location.svc/json/location/52.0222/12.3698
is not the right way to call the service.

I tried with http://localhost:52747/Location.svc/json/location/?lat=55.68743&lon=12.50400

and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 Encoding to get rid of any illegal char errors